# Unable to SSH into Docker container running Alpine Linux 3.10

Tags: linux, docker, ssh, openssh, alpine-linux

I am having problems using SSH to connect into a Docker container (from [this image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/timescale/timescaledb/latest-pg11-bitnami/images/sha256-d518d9110140922867344813d28a52eaa1ca25d7ef15cfe8f3d677d619d4ff7a?context=explore)) running Alpine Linux 3.10.

SSH must be used for this connection, as I am using a backup software `barman` which requires an SSH connection to the PostgreSQL 11 database running inside the Docker container.

First I connected into the docker container using

```
docker exec -it <container_name> /bin/bash
```

then tried to reinstall and start `sshd`

```
bash-5.0# apk add openssh --no-cache
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
OK: 117 MiB in 42 packages

bash-5.0# apk add openrc --no-cache
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
OK: 117 MiB in 42 packages

bash-5.0# rc-update add sshd
 * rc-update: sshd already installed in runlevel `sysinit'; skipping

bash-5.0# /etc/init.d/sshd start
 * WARNING: sshd is already starting
```

However, I am unable to connect to the local `sshd` server from inside the Docker container

```
# ssh root@127.0.0.1
ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused
```

Similarly, connecting into the Docker container via SSH from the Ubuntu host machine fails as well.

```
$ ssh postgres@172.26.0.4
ssh: connect to host 172.26.0.4 port 22: Connection refused
```

where 172.26.0.4 is the IP address shown from running `ifconfig` inside the Docker container.

Any ideas how we can solve this?

Comment: In linux systems, running images are in memory - so reinstalling it doesn't replace what is running... only what's on the disk. You should stop the daemon, then start it again. Then try connecting.

Comment: _obligatory why are you needing to do this question_

Comment: @johnharris85 Updated question with the reason: I am using a backup software `barman` which requires an SSH connection to the PostgreSQL 11 database running inside the Docker container.

Answer (score 7):

I didn't download the image you're referring to, but worked w/ the default docker alpine-image.  To get ssh to run inside the container a few extra steps were required - there's a good chance that you need to take the same:

```
ssh-keygen -A
rc-status
touch /run/openrc/softlevel
/etc/init.d/sshd start
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be relevant to your issue if you used --net=host along with docker run command:

We were facing similar issues with running SSH server inside our Ubuntu container.
We realized that the SSH server on the container's host was running and it used the same port that container's SSH server wanted to use.

We changed the port used by the SSH server to solve this issue.

Please note, our Docker container used --net=host and hence both container and host had the same IP address. Hence, the 2 SSH servers were fighting over a single port and that didn't allow the server inside the container to start properly.